# In Java is there an equivalent of the Convert class from C#?

Tags: java

In C# I liked using the Convert class.  It made converting from one type to another easy and consistent.  I was thinking about writing a similar class in Java, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  So I googled around to see if such a thing exists and wasn't getting good results.  So is anyone aware of something like this either in the standard libs, google guava, or apache commons?

Comment: I'm just going to comment that creating a wrapper class like this is completely pointless for java...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is no class like this in java.**

The accepted practice in java is to just cast primitives to each other.  This is an easy and consistent way of converting from one type to another.

```
float bar = 4.0f;
int foo = (int) bar;
```

Comment: And for converting primitives to strings, it's `Integer.parseInt`, `Float.parseFloat`, and so forth.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm aware of these methods.  C# has them to.  The C# Convert class is a convenience class.  It's completely unnecessary, but it makes code cleaner and quicker to type out.

Comment: People that are habituated to a particular paradigm will always miss those conventions when they migrate to something else.  In reality, a convenience class for casting among basic value types in Java is unnecessary (and possibly obfuscating).  When I came over from Visual Basic 6, I missed the Choose(i, args...) function so I still write one in to this day (it's a one liner) but it's really not necessary (and since all the args must be evaluated there is a performance tradeoff).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Convert class easily

```
package com.abc;

public class Convert {
  public static int ToInt(Object obj) {
    try{
      return Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      return 0;
    }
  }
  public static float ToFloat(Object obj) {
    try{
      return Float.parseFloat(obj.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      return 0f;
    }
  }

  public static boolean ToBoolean(Object obj){
    try{
      if(obj.getClass() == Boolean.class)
        return (Boolean)obj;

      return Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The above class passing following unit test:

```
package com.abc;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ConvertTest {

  @Test
  public void ConvertToInt() {
    assertEquals(1, Convert.ToInt(1));
    assertEquals(0, Convert.ToInt("Suresh"));
    assertEquals(0, Convert.ToInt(null));
    assertEquals(0, Convert.ToInt(true));
    assertEquals(0, Convert.ToInt(3.3f));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Test
  public void ConvertToFloat() {
    assertEquals(1f, Convert.ToFloat(1), 0.001f);
    assertEquals(0f, Convert.ToFloat("Suresh"), 0.001f);
    assertEquals(0f, Convert.ToFloat(null), 0.001f);
    assertEquals(0f, Convert.ToFloat(true), 0.001f);
    assertEquals(3.3f, Convert.ToFloat(3.3f), 0.001f);
  }

  @Test
  public void ConvertToBoolean() {
    assertEquals(false, Convert.ToBoolean(1));
    assertEquals(false, Convert.ToBoolean("Suresh"));
    assertEquals(false, Convert.ToBoolean(null));
    assertEquals(true, Convert.ToBoolean(true));
    assertEquals(false, Convert.ToBoolean(false));
    assertEquals(false, Convert.ToBoolean(3.3f));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buildung up on Suresh Prajapati's answer, converting all numbers to Strings and then parsing them back to numbers again seems a bit inefficient. I'd suggest something like:

```
public class Convert {
  public static int ToInt(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Number) {
        return ((Number)obj).intValue();
    }
    if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
        return ((Boolean)obj).booleanValue() ? 1 : 0;
    }
    try {
      return Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public static float ToFloat(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Number) {
        return ((Number)obj).floatValue();
    }
    if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
        return ((Boolean)obj).booleanValue() ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }
    try {
      return Float.parseFloat(obj.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      return 0f;
    }
  }

  public static boolean ToBoolean(Object obj){
    if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
      return ((Boolean)obj).booleanValue();
    }
    if (obj instanceof Number) {
      return (((Number)obj).longValue() != 0L);
    }
    try {
      return Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** The `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double` and so on classes
*all* are sub-classes of `Number`.